# React Native - How to delay a start

Tags: react-native

Hi everybody I'm trying to make a countdown timer with a lot of customizations but my first problem is how to delay the start of it.

It starts with 0 seconds and takes a bit to get the value I passed from the previous page

```
const CountDownScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

  const meditationTime = route.params.time;
```

I take the time

```
  const getMedTime = () => {
    let res = meditationTime;
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(res));
  };
```

state to put the time I'll get

```
const [timeToGive, setTimeToGive] = useState();


  useEffect(() => {
    const setTimeState = async () => {
      const getTime = await getMedTime();
      console.log('get time', getTime);
      // setGotTime(getTime);

      let timeToGive = {
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: getTime,
      };

      setTimeToGive(timeToGive);
    };
    setTimeState();

    updateTimer();
  }, []);
```

state with the time

```
  const [time, setTime] = useState(
    {
      eventDate: moment.duration().add(timeToGive),
    },
  );
```

the timer starts (I suppose after the PROMISE)

```
  const updateTimer = () => {
    const x = setInterval(() => {
      let { eventDate } = time;

      if (eventDate <= 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        sessionEnded();
      } else {

        eventDate = eventDate.subtract(1, 's');

        const mins = eventDate.minutes();
        const secs = eventDate.seconds();

        setTime({
          mins,
          secs,
          eventDate,
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
    setIntervalTime(x);
  };
```

I tried a lot of different solutions but none worked.
It always starts late 
I would like to avoid a `setTimeout` is there any better function?
Thanks !

Comment: What you mean it "starts late" ?

Comment: thanks. if I the timer stays on 0:0 and if I console log the time is actually 0 for the first 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are using setInterval, which starts only after 1 second (in your case).

You should probably readapt your code and do something like that :

```js
  x(); // Call x once

  setInterval(() => {
   x(); 
  }, 1000); // Call x after every seconds
```

You can store the intervalId into a state, that way you can clear it.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. I think I have to force it to start afeter the time state is filled and not before. with a promise or something

Comment: I meant that I have to force it to wait for the state time and then to let it start

Comment: When you call "setInterval(..., 1000)", it will only execute the function after 1000ms, and then, it will repeat every 1000ms. That's why you have 1 second delay at the beginning. If you don't want to get this first delay, you have to execute the function one time, before calling setInterval.

Comment: I got that, but I din't how to. `updateTimer` holds `setInterval` and then `x`